# Using the same WPF application for standalone and on web

Tags: wpf, xbap

I have an XBAP (WPF on browser) application that I want to run as a standalone application and also in the browser. How can I do that without making a lot of code changes, since going forward we will be doing a lot of modifications to the code anyway. And it is not a good idea to maintain 2 different codebases for that.

Comment: Why do you need a standalone application if you have a web browser application?  Is there any functional difference?

Comment: I need the application in 2 different ways since a master will host the web-based one where it is serve and "master" purpose. Otherwise, users should be able to download the application locally and use it. Is it possible to install an XBAP application using ClickOnce? If yes, then only the web one will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I would have 2 Projects under one Solution. One for `Project.Web` and one for `Project.Desktop`. Assuming you already have `Project.Web` underway and are adding `Project.Desktop` as new, use Visual Studio's "**Add As Link**" when adding files from `Web` to `Desktop`. This will maintain 1 copy of each file.

Host your main UI in a `UserControl`, then add that `UserControl` to the `Project.Web.Page1` (or whatever it's called) and `Project.Desktop.MainWindow`. If you modularize your program sufficiently, you won't have to worry about maintaining 2 projects since they will both be thin shells atop your main `UserControl`.

Comment: +1 - For the "Add As Link".  I can't believe all this time what I wanted was right in front of me (only slightly hidden).

Comment: It's too hidden IMO. There should really be an "Add as Link" button right beside the regular "Add" button. Every developer remembers where he/she was at the moment they got burned by that hidden button.